# Mule ESB DataMapper: Aggregation of ALL fields conditional to field type but in a nested structure

Tags: dictionary, mule, esb

This is not a duplicate question.  The previous question asked how to aggregate a conditional field type, but this one asks how to do that within a nested loop.

Please notice the  tag that seperates the structure in a way the previous question did not

Mule ESB DataMapper: Aggregation of ALL fields conditional to field type but in a nested structure.

I have the following structures:

Strcuture A:

```
<itemlist>
  <catalog>
    <name>First</name>
    <item>
      <id>123</id>
      <price>1</price>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <type>AAA</type>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>124</id>
      <price>2</price>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <type>BBB</type>
    </item>
  </catalog>
  <catalog>
    <name>Second</name>
    <item>
      <id>125</id>
      <price>3</price>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <type>BBB</type>
    </item>
  </catalog>
<itemlist>
```

Structure B:

```
<totals>
  <total>
    <totalPrice>3</totalPrice>
  </total>
</totals>
```

If I want a sumation of all the  field, but only
for structures with a  of "BBB".

BUT, I want it to iterate through all of the  
endtries, not just one.  How would I do this, and
which node should I make a rule for

Thanks

Comment: Actually this is a different question.  It is similar, but it adds a bit of complexity to the former question.  The questions are all unique, but each one has an additional complexity to them.  So it is not a duplicate

Comment: The only difference seems that there's one extra level of nesting on the elements, which can be solved the same way as the other question, ie with an XPath expression that is almost the same, if not the exact same.